# Can't install an iPhone developer certificate in keychain

Tags: iphone, certificate

So I looked everywhere and I have no idea how to solve this certificate problem. Basically, I am the team leader for the project. I have two computers - one one of them everything properly: I have the keys, certificates, etc. and I can install the app on any provisioned device.

Now, on my second computer I just can't get to install the dev certificate on keychain. Basically here is what I did:

1. Went to the provisioning portal and downloaded my certificate from Certificates --> Development (I am guessing that here I did not have to request a CSR again, since I have it already on the portal - right? Regardless, I can't see on the portal how I can request another one...)
2. Downloaded the WWDR certificate from the same page: Certificates --> Development

Now, it's weird cause when I double click on the certificate nothing happens on my keychain besides adding two keys - a private and a public under 'keys' but NOTHING under "My Certificate"

Also - when double clicking on developer_identiy.cer, nothing happens. 
Any ideas? I have literally tried everything...thanks!

Comment: What happens when you drag it to the keychain?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't install a certificate on a different machine that the CSR (cert request) was generated from just from the certificate. The reason is this stuff is based on asymmetric cryptography, also called Public-key crypto. The machine you generated the CSR on created a Private key, and stored that in it's keychain, but sent it's public key along with the CSR. When Apple generates the cert, they use your public key in the creation of the Cert. In order for you to use that cert, the machine must have both your private and public keys in the keychain. You can export your public/private keys from the original machine and import them on your second computer, and then you'll be able to use your cert on both machines. Note: it's very important you keep your private key private - don't share it with other users, don't put it on a public file share. Loose that and you'll have trouble. Look under ["Managing your digital identities"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html) for instructions on how to backup & restore your key pair.

Comment: Ok, I got it. That was very helpful and it works now. I was under the impression that every user on every machine has to download this one certificate that was generated once by the team lead. So a follow up question - does every new member has to request approval from apple for a new certificate? (the CSR)? Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad it helped. Remember to hit the 'checkmark' next to an answer that solves your problem, that'll increase your rank and encourage others to help you. Yes, each developer needs to create their own cert request and submit it. Then you as the admin will approve each one, and they're good to go. Make sure they also backup their key pair, in case they need to reinstall the OS or get a new machine.

Comment: Cool thanks, and just marked the check ;) I am new here and was sure that if I check it, people will stop reading this question since it was marked as "Resolved", but anyway, just did it. Thanks again, that's super helpful!

Comment: Glad it helped, and welcome to SO. You may be surprised how many people will comment on questions marked as answered; you can un-answer a question if someone gives you a better answer at a later time. Also, you can 'vote up' helpful answers, even if you mark a different answer as 'solved'. Lastly (and you did this with your question which is why I up-voted your question) be sure you research your question and show that, somehow, in the text (links, references, etc). If it's a code question, show what code you have so far even if it doesn't work. That'll encourage more people to help you

Comment: okay then, so you import it. HOW? Keychain has no option to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to highlight both the certificate AND private key in Keychain before clicking export. If I only highlighted one of them and exported, when the other developer double clicked the .p12 it wouldn't add to his Keychain.